# angular - ngIf collection of conditions as class

Tags: angular-ng-if

let say that i have 10 `<p>` elements,
and i want to add for them `*ngIf` condition like this:

```
`*ngIf="myconditions"`
```

is there any way to create something like this "class":

```
class myConditions{
     if  myconditions==true
          return true
     else 
          return false
}
```

or even without "return" statment:

```
class myConditions{
      myconditions....     
}
```

and then to writhe something like this:
`<p *ngIf="myConditions">` ?

it's can to be very helpful in case of long and complex or long conditions ,especially in case of many element like my `<p>` example above.

i try to do it with function:

```
num:number=1;
 myNgIf(): Boolean {
     if (this.num == 1) {
          return true;
     }
          return false;
 }
```

but angular check it's only in the first time. in case of changing the data of `num` (See the example above) variable to 10 for example, the wiew does not change,  it's not  real "binding"...

Answer (score 0):

Call the function with curly brackets.